# PDF viewer for Drupal

Tags: 7, files

I'm searching for a PDF viewer for Drupal 7 which doesn't renders as a Mozilla Firefox PDF or a google's PDF.

Does someone know anything that I could use?

Comment: Try something like http://viewerjs.org/ ( ViewerJS must be the easiest way to use presentations, spreadsheets, PDF's and other documents on your website or blog without any external dependencies.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're looking for the [PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf) module

> Uses HTML5 to display PDF files if users don't have pdf plugin for their browsers.
>
> With this module you can use pdf.js to display PDF file all the time or only use pdf.js when visitors don't have pdf reader plugin.